# Start point to lower corner when drawing by a mouse

Tags: c#, paint, picturebox

How to me to change a code that when drawing on picturebox of coordinate undertook not from the first pressing of a mouse, and from the left bottom corner of picturebox?

```cs
    private void Pic_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        toDraw = false;
    }

    private void Pic_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (toDraw)
        {
            topLeft = new Point
            {
                X = pointBegin.X < e.X ? pointBegin.X : e.X,
                Y = pointBegin.Y < e.Y ? pointBegin.Y : e.Y
            };
            bottomRight = new Point
            {
                X = pointBegin.X > e.X ? pointBegin.X : e.X,
                Y = pointBegin.Y > e.Y ? pointBegin.Y : e.Y
            };

            Pic.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void Pic_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.DarkOrange, 2),
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(topLeft.X, topLeft.Y,
                bottomRight.X - topLeft.X, bottomRight.Y - topLeft.Y));
        dotLeftX = topLeft.X;
        X1.Text = "X1: " + dotLeftX.ToString();
        dotLeftY = topLeft.Y;
        Y1.Text = "Y1: " + dotLeftY.ToString();
        dotRightX = bottomRight.X;
        X2.Text = "X2: " + dotRightX.ToString();
        dotRightY = bottomRight.Y;
        Y2.Text = "Y2: " + dotRightY.ToString();

    }
```

http://i.imgbox.com/aazyql16.gif

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question. I don't understand exactly what you want.

Comment: I want that X1 and Y1 values began from the bottom left corner of picturebox, in not dependences movement of a mouse from where began.

Comment: That is, I mean that in function
public Rectangle (int x, int y, int width, int height);

X-th and Y values were counted from the bottom left corner.